# Shopware 6 Flow Builder: How to best share Flow Sequences using files

Tags: shopware, shopware6

Is there a way to share Flow sequences with other people over git or files?

Example: I change Flow sequence in the Flow Builder and want to share the new Flow with my coworker’s installation of Shopware after they check out my branch.

My only idea is to create a Migration for each change, but this will require a lot of them over the course of development.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's currently not possible, you have to take into account that the flows may also reference data that is not existend in the other shop etc.

However there is an upcoming feature that is currently being build called `Flow Templates`, that improves the sharing between flows. Take a look at the [roadmap](https://www.shopware.com/de/roadmap/) to monitor the progress.

However the flow export functionality will be part of the `Rise` edition.

Answer (score 1):

That's an upcoming feature on the [roadmap](https://www.shopware.com/en/roadmap/), see `Flow Templates`.